# Developer story: "Read more" fade mask isn't correctly aligned with text

Tags: bug, design, developer-story

The mask to fade out the last line before the "Read more" jump in Developer Story items cuts the descenders off the bottom of that line, and cuts off some of the line above as well. I'm guessing it's an(other) issue with scaling on high-dpi displays.

[image: screenshot of bug]

Since I got a complaint on my previous bug report for not including a freehand circle, I thought I'd include one here :-)

Firefox 49.0.2 on Windows 10, with a 4k monitor. The "change the size of text" slider is set to 150%. (But you should be able to tell that from the pixel size of text in the screenshot.)