# Developer Story description text is cut off in Firefox

Tags: bug, design, developer-story, user-experience

I've edited my developer story and added a few words of description under a "Blogs or videos" section. It looks bad.

[image]

There are two bugs here:

- The text should not be faded, and the *Read more* button should not be displayed - the text is short enough to fit on the last line.
- The white gradient hides half of the previous line, making the text illegible ([also reported here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337569/7586), but it is worse in my case).

This is the same in Firefox and Edge (it looks well on Chrome).

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/story/kobi